# Creating index in hive 0.9

Tags: hadoop, indexing, hive

I am trying to create index on tables in Hive 0.9. One table has 1 billion rows, another has 30 Million rows. The command I used is (other than creating the table and so on)

```
  CREATE INDEX DEAL_IDX_1 ON TABLE DEAL (ID) AS 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.index.compact.CompactIndexHandler'
  WITH DEFERRED REBUILD;

  alter index DEAL_IDX_1 ON DEAL rebuild;

  set hive.optimize.autoindex=true;
  set hive.optimize.index.filter=true;
```

For the 30 Mill. row table, the rebuilding process looks alright (mapper and reducer both finished) until in the end it prints

```
  Invalid alter operation: Unable to alter index.
  FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 
  from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

Checking the log, and it had the error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"
```

Not sure why this error was encountered, but anyway, I added the derby-version.jar:

```
add jar /path/derby-version.jar
```

The reported error was resolved, but still got another error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator: 
StatsPublishing error: cannot connect to database
```

Not sure how to solve the problem. I do see the created index table under hive/warehouse though.

For the 1 Billion row table, it is another story. The mapper just got stuck at 2% or so. And error showed

```
FATAL org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child: Error running child : 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I attempted to enforce max heap size, as well as max mapr memory (see the settings mentioned somewhere but not in hive's configuration settings):

```
set mapred.child.java.opts =  -Xmx6024m
set mapred.job.map.memory.mb=6000;
set mapred.job.reduce.memory.mb=4000;
```

However, this is not help. The mapper would still got stuck at 2% with the same error.

Comment: why do you need to create the index?

Comment: @cybye, that is an interesting question. It is not very clear how index would help performance of my queries. I  would like to benchmark and tune the  performance. The table had a few columns on which multiple select conditions will be run. There are also a few join operations on the tables.

Comment: maybe you can gain performance with the partitioning (metastore provided index) and bucketing the tables first? I'm not sure where the errors above come from. The derby-problem is probably, because you have a local metastore only. it could help to start a metastore server (start server, in hive hive metastore local false and set the urls).

Comment: @cybye, I can think of the scenario where partitioning improves query execution dramatically. For example, if the table has `add_timestamp`, I may partition records according to (`year, month, day`, etc) then queries that involving `select/filter` on timestamp would be efficient. However, assume the table has other columns (say `location` that has no correlation to `timestamp`) on which I would do `select/filter`. The tables are already physically partitioned according to timestamp. To me an **index** on `location` in this scenario is very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem of the index creating and in the hive/warehouse, but the process as a whole failing. My index_name was TypeTarget (yours is DEAL_IDX_1) and after many days of trying different approaches, making the index_name all lowercase (typetarget) fixed the issue. My problem was in Hive 0.10.0.

Also, the class not found and StatsPublishing issue is because by default, hive.stats.autogather is turned on. Turning that off (false) in hive-site.xml should get rid of those issues.

Hopefully this helps anyone looking for a quick fix.

Comment: From https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Indexing#LanguageManualIndexing-SimpleExamples a warning: ``Case sensitivity
Icon
In Hive 0.12.0 and earlier releases, the index name is case-sensitive for CREATE INDEX and DROP INDEX statements. However, ALTER INDEX requires an index name that was created with lowercase letters (see HIVE-2752). This bug is fixed in Hive 0.13.0 by making index names case-insensitive for all HiveQL statements. For releases prior to 0.13.0, the best practice is to use lowercase letters for all index names.```